# What this string formatation do?

Tags: c

I met this code:

```
unsigned char c = 0xA3;
printf("%2.2X\n",c);
```

But I don't know what the purpose of `2.2` is. When I compare these two statements:

```
printf("%2.2X\n",c);
printf("%X\n",c);
```

I get the same output, such as:

**A3**

Than what `2.2` stands for?
Thank you.

Comment: [RTFM](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivially answerable by R'ing the FM.

Comment: Have you tried it with other values? For example `unsigned int` values with fewer, and more, textual digits. Note that the `unsigned char` you passed is promoted to `unsigned int`. Experiment.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Again: Do not link to C++ documentation when asked for behaviour of C functions. C++ is a different language than C and the library behaves slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%A.BX\n", c);
```

`A` is the minimum amount of characters the output must have. If there's less than this, then it'll fill the remaining spaces to the left with blank spaces. Example: `printf("%3.1X\n", 6); -> "  6"`

`B` is the minimum amount of digits the output must have. If there's less than this, it'll fill the remaining with zeroes to the left. Example: `printf("%4.2X\n", 6); -> "  06"`

`X` means the output will be in hexadecimal, with the letters in caps. Example: `printf("%7.5X\n", 232) -> "  000E8"`